# How to resolve merge conflicts when an intermediary branch must be used?

Tags: git

I am making changes to a repository but I do not have write access. I forked their repo and first implement the changes in my copy. Then I ask the owners to merge those changes to a feature branch in their base repo. Then I request that their feature branch will be merged to master.

While I was testing my changes in QA from the feature branch, another branch was merged to master which created merge conflicts. I solved them in my local and pushed to my own branch. My branch was green with no merge conflicts. Then it was merged (by the owners) into the feature branch. At this time, the merge conflicts re-appeared.

My PR includes changes to a CloudFormation file which is only allowed from users with write access. This means that I cannot merge directly to master, aka it requires me to first merge my changes to the feature branch.

I pulled the changes in a variety of ways to no avail. I tried creating a new branch off of master and then pulling my changes on top. Same problem. Any time I merge to a branch, it resets the merge conflicts for the 2nd merge.

Comment: *“Then it was merged (by the owners) into the feature branch. At this time, the merge conflicts re-appeared.”* Did they actually do a real merge, or did they squash/rebase your changes onto the feature branch (which wouldn’t resolve conflicts)?